# Retrieve data from one table that is not in another one

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
sq = "select roomno,blockname from roommanage where roomno not in( select *from availableroom)";
ds = dc.filldata(sq);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["t1"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

There is an error:

`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXIST`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in your "not in" should only return 1 column. Try below code.

```
sq = "select roomno,blockname from roommanage where roomno not in( select id from availableroom)";
    ds = dc.filldata(sq);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["t1"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: how can i return 2 coloumn?

Comment: when you are using "not in" it should return only 1 column or else it will error. What do you want to expect in your result?

Answer (score 0):

for two column try this

```
    sq = "SELECT roomno,blockname FROM roommanage 
WHERE roomno NOT IN( SELECT id FROM availableroom) 
AND blockname NOT IN(SELECT yourcolumn FROM blockname)";
ds = dc.filldata(sq);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["t1"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```